# Best way for internationalization management with locize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

I'm working on ReactJS project which is using locize as internationalization service and i18next library. I encounter the problem about add/update translation on locize. Here is the problem:

Currently, we add/update translation by 2 ways:

1. Using locize editor to directly update translation on locize (usually done by operation team)
2. We have translation file in source code repo, we use it for local environment then when release the feature, we will import this file to locize (usually done by dev team).

The issue is that when operation team updates some text directly on locize (in this time the translation file in the source code is still on the old version). Then when release a new feature dev team try to import translation file from source code (which update other text) to locize, the changes that operation team has made got overrided (make it revert back to the old version). Does anyone have experience about how to resolve it?

I appreciate any helps. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

normally there are 2 approaches:

1. dev-team is working on the latest version and operation team on a review version. And from time to time the versions get merged: https://docs.locize.com/more/versioning#merging-versions
2. dev-team uses the [locize-cli](https://github.com/locize/locize-cli#step-3-execute) with the sync argument “ --compare-modification-time true”

Comment: Hi adrai, thanks for reply. But I'm worried about that sometimes operation team modify/update translation directly on review version (version used on production). From there, the version for dev team does not take that update

Comment: then you can use the “COPY TO” functionality from time to time, to verify if there is something to be merged back